# Does Samba have a default password?

Tags: samba

```
$ smbpasswd
Old SMB password:
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
Could not connect to machine 127.0.0.1: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

One suggestion was to add the user to samba

```
smbpasswd -a frank
```

This brought up list of options, should it tell me user added?

Samba quick start guide use smbadduser name:name but that gave command not found

Did that but when I retry to change password I get same error message.

Browsing around it suggests that this error message is that you did not enter old password, as it is a new install I presumed it to be blank and googling samba default password came up with 1234 as default password, so tried that in the old SMB password... same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to add a user.

```
useradd -c "User Name" -d /home/user -s /sbin/nologin user
```

The create a password for that user

```
smbpasswd -a user
New SMB password:
Retype new SMB password:
```

and you will get

Added user user.

After that, you have to define shares.  Let me know if it works.

*Make sure you replace User Name and user, with the real user

Try `run passwd`, then `sudo smbpasswd`

Comment: useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later

Just wonder that is because my username already exists? I do not want a different user name. Also entering the smbpasswd -a user just brings up command options no prompt

Comment: did you try `smbpasswd -a frank`

Comment: OOps I had not changed other ´user' did so and got useradd: user 'frank' already exists
So I guess I was right there

Comment: Try creating a another user, and see if it will let you login.

Comment: Yes I got  - $ smbpasswd -a frank
When run by root:
    smbpasswd [options] [username]
otherwise:
    smbpasswd [options]

options:
 etcetera

Comment: Nope -  same problem....  useradd -c "test" -d /home/test -s /sbin/nologin test
useradd: cannot lock /etc/passwd; try again later.

Comment: as I didn't want to add another user I tried the sudo sbmpasswwd -a frank and it did not give an error :) It did not give a confirm either? Thank you for your help. I did not know about using sudo in front of a command before.

Comment: Have to run Samba again I guess, then go to windows box and see if I can log into share

Comment: did not seem to have worked. I ran sbmpasswd again without the -a. Typed in my password as old password and again as new password... this time it gave the message Password changed for user frank :) but still not recognising from Win. Guess I have to reboot ubuntu

Comment: Well something seems to have gone right :) I can finally access Ubuntu box from Windows... gotta a whole bundle of shares showing :) It was clearly that sudo that did the trick Thanks Mitch

Answer (score 4):

First check if your account already exists among smbdclients:

```
sudo pdbedit -L
```

if the account is not there just run (e.g on pc: myaccount@server):

```
sudo smbpasswd -a myaccount
```

otherwise if already exists, you have to delete first and recreate a new one:

```
sudo pdbedit -x -u myaccount 
sudo smbpasswd -a myaccount
```